# Fonts not rendering from CDN/S3

Tags: css, fonts, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I am currently having issues with fonts rendering correctly in Firefox that are hosted on a CDN using S3. If I run the site locally, I get the fonts running great in all browsers. When I run it on a Heroku instance (sandbox) it works great.

But when I run the application on our "acceptance" box, everything gets served up via a CDN. And the fonts fail to render.

I've made sure to customize the CORS file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://acceptance.somesite.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>30000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>HOST</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I've used the following resource with no success:

- http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/
- http://www.bryandragon.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline-cdns-and-serving-cross-domain-fonts/
- https://github.com/rubymaverick/font_assets

It looks to me that the headers are fine?

curl -i -X OPTIONS http://acceptance.builder.mhelabs.com/

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://acceptance.somesite.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2013 19:44:48 GMT
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

curl -i http://cdn.somesite.com/assets/my-webfont-3ae860b18413d5.woff

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 27156
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://acceptance.somesite.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
Age: 0
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2013 19:42:31 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Oct 2013 19:04:08 GMT
Status: 200 OK
X-Content-Digest: 3c885674980901337099e06dc284e25dabf083c1
X-Rack-Cache: miss, store
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 d5a6610c68af624ff3a6a9cdee479708.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: BJfEd-Z-juJgguV1wqZ6AL-Yh5eFkGz2xSwja7UQMxQpKL3M9m1HMA==
```

Any help with this would be awesome.

Comment: Could it be possibly the proxy setup you have at your location? Trying to access the link to the font file from here, I got blocked due to "proxy avoidance".

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira I actually substituted the link above :)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the link was *somesite.com* :) Seems like an issue that doesnt happen in Chrome as well, so wont be able to test much here :P

Answer (score 0):

If a non-Firefox browser makes the first (fresh) request, S3 will fail to return the requisite HTTP headers and that (unhelpful) response will get cached by the CDN.

Instead of using S3+CloudFront for web fonts, use a live app (with a real server) that *always* serves the correct HTTP headers for web fonts so that the CDN is guaranteed to cache the necessary response.